# Communicating with iframe on same origin

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, browser, rxjs

In my application(angular 6) it is required to communicate with `iframe` on same origin, is there any better way to communicate with `iframe` on same-origin other than using global `window` object. If some sort of wrapper or through by RxJS.

P.S. : I have also checked the storage example, I want to know your opinions  if can achieve same in better way without polluting window object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between two `<iframe>`.

A *message* event is fired each time a message is received. So it's possible to construct an observable with [fromEvent](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent) if you wish to do so.

Here's a quick example:

I have `ping.html` which includes `pong.html` as an iframe. *(Both are hosted on http://localhost:8000)*

1. `ping.html` initiates the first message to `pong.html`
2. When `pong.html` receives a message, it displays '' and sends a response back
3. When `ping.html` receives a message, it displays '' and sends a response back
4. And so on...

Here's `ping.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="msg_from_pong"></div>
    <iframe id="pong" src="pong.html" style="width:100%;border-style:none"></iframe>

    <script>

      // Wait until the pong iframe is loaded
      document.querySelector('#pong').addEventListener('load', ({target}) => {
        target.contentWindow.postMessage('initial ping', 'http://localhost:8000');
      });

      // Listen to message from the pong iframe
      window.addEventListener('message', ({data, source, origin}) => {
        if (data !== 'pong') {
          return;
        }

        document.querySelector('#msg_from_pong')
          .appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));

        setTimeout(() => {
          source.postMessage('ping', origin);
        }, 300);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's `pong.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="msg_from_ping"></div>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('message', ({data, source, origin}) => {

        document.querySelector('#msg_from_ping')
          .appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));

        setTimeout(() => {
          source.postMessage('pong', origin);
        }, 300);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the full thing in action:

[image]